# Rails 6: render new list based on selection in first list

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating an application that will display two lists, the second of which is rendered based on the selection in the first list. All on the same page without reloading.

The first list is created from all of the names in model VehicleCategory.

Vehicles `belong_to` VehicleCategory, and VehicleCategory `has_many` Vehicles.

The second list should be a seperate identical list, the list items of which should be in its own div.

The first list is rendered like so:

```
---in main view:

<div class="list-group">
<%= render @allvehiclecategories %>
</div>

---in controller:

def main
  @allvehiclecategories = Vehiclecategory.all 
end

---and in _vehiclecategory.html.erb:

<%= content_tag :a, class: ["list-group-item", "list-group-item-action"] do -%>
       <%= klass.name %>
<% end -%>
```

and uses this jquery to add bootstrap class "active" to the list item selected:

```
    $('.list-group a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $that = $(this);

    $that.parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
    $that.addClass('active');
    });
```

**what is the best way to go about creating the second list?**

Comment: It is not exactly clear how you want your second list to show up on the page. Do you want it nested in the first list or in a separate list?

Comment: i will clarify! it will be a seperate list.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its scope is way to broad.

Comment: go ahead, i agree i need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are many roads that lead to Rome. When you are sure there are not too many vehicles you can just add all of them somewhere in you html and make them invisible at first and make them visible in a click event. But I can imagine there are a lot of vehicles in that case you should not do this because it will take forever to load the page.

Another option is to fetch the vehicles you would like to show via a http request (AJAX) from you Rails app and add them to the second list. You could either return html or json. When using html you can just add this to the page when using json you need to build the html in you javascript. Since you are using jQuery you can use the [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method to fetch them from your rails app.

Here is a nice [blog post](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/) about using the AJAX approach that returns html from Rails.

Comment: I suppose my open ended question deserved an open ended response. I appreciate the response!